# Removing <ul> bullets via CSS

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

I am using jQuery for the first time via the Views Cycle module for Drupal. I am not a CSS pro, but I am pulling my hair out trying to remove the bullets from the rotating images on this page: http://shoshannabauer.com/

What am I missing? Does the list-style go on the <li> or on the <ul> class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some jQuery which will remove the bullet for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul.viewsCycle-processed').css({background:'transparent'}).find('> li').css({background:'transparent'});
});
```

And if you want to add a css stylesheet to the page:

```
ul.viewsCycle-processed { background:transparent !important; }
ul.viewsCycle-processed li { background:transparent !important; }
```

Comment: This one was actually the most reliable. While you would expect that list-style: none would work, it did not unless I set it site wide. Instead, it looks like the HTML this page was using needed to have the background for the ul's set to transparent to override.

Comment: That's really unnecessary, it's just covering up a missed bug or style somewhere.

Comment: Well, he could change the styles in the css file, but if he ever updates the cycle plugin and overwrites the stylesheet, he'll have the same problem.  The jQuery is a little overkill, but that's how his question was tagged.  Adding the styles inline on the page containing the cycling images would prevent this problem on updates (as long as they don't update class names) and it will occur immediately since it's not javascript.

Comment: @Shawn, and the 'bug' is that the plugin uses background styles to generate the bullets instead of list-style.

Answer (score 16):

`list-style` goes on the `<ul>` class.

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: I think that doesn't matter in this case, bacause the list-elements have customized bullets in the form of an background-image of a bullet and padding-left for the text.

Comment: The custom bullets you're referring to are in the left menu, not on the images he's trying to remove them from.

Comment: And, obviously, the OP can limit this to a specific class rather than just UL, but this was just an example.

Comment: Here's a great article I always reference on this very topic: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Answer (score 5):

**edit:** Shawn is right. This here is the reason for the bullets in your navigation on the left.

Take a look at your css, you have an image of a bullet there.

```
li.leaf {
    background:transparent url(images/menu-leaf.gif) no-repeat scroll 1px 0.4em;
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

Your list elements have kind of custom bullets in the form of a `background-image` of a white bullet and a `padding-left` of `1.5em`

Comment: Congratulations! You were the first to actually look at the page! +1

Comment: The .leaf class only applies to the navigation menu on the left.  The OP is trying to remove the standard bullets from the images in the body of the page, which have no class on the LI elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try using list-style-type on the list

```
ul { list-style-type:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
list-style: none;
```

on `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to RamboNo5's answer:

```
ul.menu li, .item-list ul li, li.leaf {
    background: none;
}
```

fixes this. The bullets were not browser-generated but background images.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, assuming you want to keep the bullets in the left menu... if you look in your `style.css?b` css file, under your `/* lists */` and remove this line, it'll fix the problem (it's a duplicate and over-riding all the other styling)

```
ul li {
 background:transparent url(images/menu-leaf.gif) no-repeat 1px .4em;
 list-style-image:none;
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list-style goes in the tag `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
list-style:none;
}
```

you might have to remove the list-style from the `li` too, in this case use:

un-ordered list item:

```
ul li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

or for ordered list item:

```
ol li{
list-style:none;
}
```

good luck